404 page not found on nginx webserver when hosted on VPS
When I host my kafka server on vps and add the nginx server for the control center authentication, I get the error 404 page not found. However this same setup works fine on my local machine when I change the nginx.conf file and replcae evey ip address with my localhost. I am using docker containers and I have 5 docker containers 2 of them are kafka brokers, 1 is zookeepr, 1 is the control center and 1 is the nginx server. Everything is working fine, the niginx logs is saying that its ready to use.
this is my nginx.conf file
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # SSL settings
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl_cert.key;

    # Gzip Settings (optional)
    gzip on;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name <VPS_ADDRESS>;  # Change to your local IP or hostname if needed

        # Proxy settings for Control Center
        location / {
            auth_basic "Restricted Access";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

            proxy_pass http://control-center:9021;  # Forward requests to Control Center
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }

        # Error page for 404
        error_page 404 /404.html;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <VPS_ADDRESS>;  # Change to your local IP or hostname if needed

        # Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

and these are docker containers for nginx and control center:

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.4.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker1
      - broker2
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"  # Control Center UI port
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker1:29092,broker2:29093'
      CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'localhost:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION: '/etc/ssl/keystore.jks'  # Path to keystore in the container
      CONTROL_CENTER_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: 'key_stroe_pw'  # Keystore password
      CONTROL_CENTER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION: '/etc/ssl/truststore.jks'  # Path to truststore in the container
      CONTROL_CENTER_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 'trust_store_pw'  # Truststore password

    volumes:
      - ./keystore.jks:/etc/ssl/keystore.jks:ro  # Mount the keystore into the container
      - ./truststore.jks:/etc/ssl/truststore.jks:ro  # Mount the truststore into the container (if applicable)
    networks:
      - confluent
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "https://localhost:9021"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro  # NGINX config
      - ./htpasswd:/etc/nginx/.htpasswd:ro  # Password file for authentication
      - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro  # Mount the SSL certificates
    ports:
      - "443:443"  # Expose SSL on port 443
      - "8080:8080"  # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    depends_on:
      - control-center
    networks:
      - confluent

I can access the control center directly from my local machine through this <VPS_ADDRESS>:9021 but I want an authentication enabled so that when I access this http://<VPS_ADDRESS> i get a prompt to add username and password and the redirect to control center.
I have tried to access the control center from nginx container, I am getting 200 response message on curl http://control-center:9021
